# How to show boundedness and calculate the norm of the linear transformation?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am having a lot of trouble with this:

> $X$ denotes the Banach space $C[0,1]$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, with $\Vert f\Vert= \max\limits_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)|$.
>   Consider the linear transformation $T\colon X \to X,$ where $T(f)$ is a function such that $$(T(f))(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{1}{(x-y)f(y)dy}.$$   Show that $T$ is bounded and find $\Vert{T} \Vert.$

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please post your efforts to solve the question. What is $X$?

Comment: Try easy $f$ to warm up. For instance $f(x)=1$. Then $f(x)=x$. See what you get. You'll get a better understanding of $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\|f\|=1$ and consider a fixed $x\in[0,1]$. Then
$$f(y)\leq 1\quad  (0\leq y\leq x)\ ,\qquad f(y)\geq-1\quad (x\leq y\leq 1)\ .$$
It follows that
$$Tf(x)\leq\int_0^x (x-y)\ dy +\int_x^1 (y-x)\ dy={1\over2}(1-2x+2x^2)\leq {1\over2}\qquad(0\leq x\leq1)\ ;$$
and similarly one proves that $Tf(x)\geq-{1\over2}$ $\ (0\leq x\leq 1)$. It follows that $$\|T\|\leq{1\over2}\ .\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, for the function $f(x):\equiv-1$ you get $$\|Tf\|\geq Tf(0)=\int_0^1 y\ dy={1\over2}={1\over2}\|f\|\ .$$ Together with $(1)$ this implies that in fact $\|T\|={1\over2}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little unclear to me. I think you need to state the problem better. What is X? Are there any conditions on f? If T is a linear operator on a Hilbert space then remember that bounded and continuous mean the same thing.